# @font-face color?

Tags: css, colors, font-face

I'm trying to put some specific font on the website using

```css
@font-face
```

Everything seems allright except the color.

Is there any way to change the color of `.otf` font in CSS?

Comment: Just the same way as you would change the colour of text normally.

Comment: By the way there are *.woff (woff2) fonts which sets a fixed color that you can't overwrite with CSS. Took me a moment to figure that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd declare using a selector.

e.g.

```css
p {
    font-family: 'AsapRegular';
    color: #c50000;
}
```

Comment: You do not declare the color in the @font-face declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to simply change the colour as your normally would:

```
p { color:red; }
```

Make sure it's not overwritten and that your declaration has a high enough specificity.